# Plotting Implicit Algebraic equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I wish to plot implicit functions in MATLAB. Like x^3 + xy + y^2 = 36 , equations which cannot be made into simple parametric form. Is there any simple method ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here are a couple of options...

### Using [`ezplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html) (or [`fplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html) recommended in newer versions):

The easiest solution is to use the function [`ezplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html):

```
ezplot('x.^3 + x.*y + y.^2 - 36', [-10 10 -10 10]);
```

Which gives you the following plot:

[image]

### Using [`contour`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html):

Another option is to generate a set of points where you will evaluate the function `f(x,y) = x^3 + x*y + y^2` and then use the function [`contour`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) to plot contour lines where `f(x,y)` is equal to 36:

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(-10:0.1:10);   % Create a mesh of x and y points
f = x.^3+x.*y+y.^2;              % Evaluate f at those points
contour(x, y, f, [36 36], 'b');  % Generate the contour plot
xlabel('x');                     % Add an x label
ylabel('y');                     % Add a y label
title('x^3 + x y + y^2 = 36');   % Add a title
```

The above will give you a plot nearly identical to the one generated by [`ezplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html):

[image]

Comment: @gnovice : It is working ! .... working good ..... but I am not very comfortable with the formulation .... anyways, whatever plots my curves :)

Comment: @gnovice: are there any other methods than ezplot ..... ezplot works great ....just asking for some alternatives  (Matlab usually has alternatives)

Comment: @Arkapravo: I added another option in addition to EZPLOT.

Answer (score 6):

In case you want to plot an implicit surface, for example a Horned cube, you can do something like the following.

The idea is to calculate all values of the function (even if they don't equal to zero)  and then create an `isosurface` that will define your equality. In this example the implicit function equals to zero.

```
fun=@(x,y,z)(1-x.^8-3.*y.^8-2.*z.^8+5.*x.^4.*z.^2.*y.^2+3.*y.^4.*x.^2.*z.^2) ;

[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(-2:0.1:2,-2:0.1:2,-2:0.1:2);

val=fun(X,Y,Z);

fv=isosurface(X,Y,Z,val,0);

p = patch(fv);
isonormals(X,Y,Z,val,p)
set(p,'FaceColor' , 'red');
set(p,'EdgeColor' , 'none');
daspect([1,1,1])
view(3); axis tight
camlight 
lighting phong
axis off
```

[image]

Additionally there is a Matlab File Exchange submission called [ezimplot3D](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23623-ezimplot3--implicit-3d-functions-plotter) that seems to do the job also, as @knedlsepp suggests.

Comment: Thanks for adding them to the answer!

Answer (score 2):

[Implot2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23548) and [implot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/300-implot-m) from Matlab Central appear to do the job.

Comment: @Justin : Thanks, will have a look

Answer (score 2):

There are two new functions to plot implicit function in R2016b:

[fimplicit](http://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fimplicit.html) for f(x,y) = 0
[fimplicit3](http://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fimplicit3.html) for f(x,y,z) = 0

Comment: because I can't comment,so I post an answer here :)