# Matlab - how to plot the intersection between an implicitly defined surface and a plane

Tags: matlab

I'm not very familiar with matlab, but I'm trying to plot the intersection of a plane (x + y + z = 1) with a surface. the surface is defined implicitly (x, y, and z as functions of alpha, beta). this is my code:

```
alpha = linspace(0,pi);
beta = linspace(0,pi);

[alpha,beta]=meshgrid(alpha,beta);

 L= 4*exp(-.6*beta).*sin(alpha);
```

%converting to x,y,z coordinates:

```
x = L.*sin(alpha).*cos(beta);
y = L.*cos(alpha);
z= L.*sin(alpha).*sin(beta);
```

to plot this i generally would use surf(x,y,z). but in this case i want to plot its intersection with a plane, for example the one defined by z2 = 1-x+y. (im not sure whether it would be better to define separate matrices for new x, y values, or whether it is better to use the existing ones.) i hope this question isn't too confusing. if you have any advice, please help.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try the following: (I based my code on this answer to a previous question [Plotting Implicit Algebraic equations in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722500/plotting-implicit-algebraic-equations-in-matlab)) and it is not perfect but maybe it can help you:

```
clear 
clc

alpha = linspace(0,pi);
beta = linspace(0,pi);

[alpha,beta]=meshgrid(alpha,beta);

 L= 4*exp(-.6*beta).*sin(alpha);

x = L.*sin(alpha).*cos(beta);
y = L.*cos(alpha);
z= L.*sin(alpha).*sin(beta);

% Use an anonymous function to define the plane you want to plot
[X,Y] = meshgrid(min(x(:)):.5:max(x(:)),min(y(:)):0.5:max(y(:))); % x and y limits
f = @(X,Y) -X+Y+1; % sorry for the choice of capital letters; it was the most intuitive I thought.

hold on

surf(x,y,z);
contour3(X,Y,f(X,Y),200); % the 200 is arbitrary; play with it to change the # of lines making up the plane

hold off

rotate3d on
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

As I said I'm not 100% confident this is the most robust way but it looks fine to me :)