# How to draw curves with two variables in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I would like to draw curves with two variables like f(x,y)=0 for example:

`x^2+y^2-2ax+2by+c=0` (a,b,c are constants and x,y are variables)

Of course in the case above, it is a circle so I could write the equation above in the form of circle and calculate its center and radius. Then I can plot it out.

But next time if it is not a circle（for example there are 'xy' terms or there are 'x^3,y^3' terms）, is there any way to plot it out in the x-y plane too?

I know how to draw f(x,y) in 3D plot using `meshgrid`, But I would like to draw f(x,y)=0 in 2D forms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting Implicit Algebraic equations in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722500/plotting-implicit-algebraic-equations-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Suggestion 1:

[`fcontour`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fcontour.html)

You would use it like this:

```
f = @(x,y) x.^2 + y.^2
fcontour(f,[xmin xmax ymin ymax])
```

This was introduced in `R2016a`.

---

#### Suggestion 2:

you may have to determine the x- and y-values for each equation and then plot those.

You could use [`anonymous functions`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to automate this. The good thing here is that you can create a cell array of anonymous functions and loop through those.

```
% // Generate the x and y values
x=-2*pi:0.01:2*pi;
y=-2*pi:0.01:2*pi;
```

Create anonymous functions that will hold your equation. It is up to you to design these as you see fit. This particular anonymous function that I did creates a matrix where the first column hold the x values and the second hold the y-values.  You will probably have different x- and y- values for each function.

```
a=@(x,y) ([cos(x);sin(y)].');   
a1 = @(x,y) ([cos(x).^2;sin(x).^2].');
```

Put them in an cell array

```
t{1} = a;
t{2} = a1;
```

Then you can loop through your anonymous functions

```
for n=1:length(t)
    f = t{n};        
    subplot(2,1,n)
    plot(f(y,x),'LineWidth',5);        
end
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can have a look at the scatterplot function: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html

[edit] or just use plot(x,y) [/edit]

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP knows how to use `plot` already, However, it especially won't work in this case because the function is implicit. Unfortunately, `scatterplot` is of no help neither here...